# Why does omp_set_dynamic(1) never adjust the number of threads (in Visual C++)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, openmp

If we look at the [Visual C++ documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/3-run-time-library-functions?view=vs-2019#317-omp_set_dynamic-function) of `omp_set_dynamic`, it is literally copy-pasted from the [OMP 2.0 standard](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/cspec20.pdf) (section 3.1.7 on page 39):

> If [the function argument] evaluates to a nonzero value, the number of threads that are used for executing upcoming parallel regions may be adjusted automatically by the run-time environment to best use system resources. As a consequence, the number of threads specified by the user is the maximum thread count. The number of threads in the team executing a parallel region stays fixed for the duration of that parallel region and is reported by the `omp_get_num_threads` function.

It seems clear that `omp_set_dynamic(1)` allows the implementation to use fewer than the current maximum number of threads for a parallel region (presumably to prevent oversubscription under high loads). Any reasonable reading of this paragraph would suggest that said reduction should be observable by querying `omp_get_num_threads` inside parallel regions.

<sup>(Both documentations also show the signature as `void omp_set_dynamic(int dynamic_threads);`. It appears that "the number of threads specified by the user" does not refer to `dynamic_threads` but instead means "whatever the user specified using the remaining OpenMP interface").</sup>

However, no matter how high I push my system load under `omp_set_dynamic(1)`, the return value of `omp_get_num_threads` (queried inside the parallel regions) never changes from the maximum in my test program. Yet I can still observe clear performance differences between `omp_set_dynamic(1)` and `omp_set_dynamic(0)`.

Here is a sample program to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

#include <omp.h>

#define UNDER_LOAD true

const int SET_DYNAMIC_TO = 1;

const int REPEATS = 3000;
const unsigned MAXCOUNT = 1000000;

std::size_t threadNumSum = 0;
std::size_t threadNumCount = 0;

void oneRegion(int i)
{
  // Pesudo-randomize the number of iterations.
  unsigned ui = static_cast<unsigned>(i);
  int count = static_cast<int>(((MAXCOUNT + 37) * (ui + 7) * ui) % MAXCOUNT);

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(guided, 512)
  for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
  {
    if (j == 0)
    {
      threadNumSum += omp_get_num_threads();
      threadNumCount++;
    }

    if ((j + i + count) % 16 != 0)
      continue;

    // Do some floating point math.
    double a = j + i;
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
      a = std::sin(i * (std::cos(a) * j + std::log(std::abs(a + count) + 1)));

    volatile double out = a;
  }
}


int main()
{
  omp_set_dynamic(SET_DYNAMIC_TO);


#if UNDER_LOAD
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    std::thread([]()
    {
      unsigned x = 0;
      float y = static_cast<float>(std::sqrt(2));
      while (true)
      {
//#pragma omp parallel for
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        {
          x = x * 7 + 13;
          y = 4 * y * (1 - y);
        }
        volatile unsigned xx = x;
        volatile float yy = y;
      }
    }).detach();
  }
#endif


  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clk;
  auto start = clk.now();

  for (int i = 0; i < REPEATS; ++i)
    oneRegion(i);

  std::cout << (clk.now() - start).count() / 1000ull / 1000ull << " ms for " << REPEATS << " iterations" << std::endl;

  double averageThreadNum = double(threadNumSum) / threadNumCount;
  std::cout << "Entered " << threadNumCount << " parallel regions with " << averageThreadNum << " threads each on average." << std::endl;

  std::getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

Compiler version: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27024.1 for x64

On e.g. gcc, this program will print a significantly lower `averageThreadNum` for `omp_set_dynamic(1)` than for `omp_set_dynamic(0)`. But on MSVC, the same value is shown in both cases, despite a 30% performance difference (170s vs 230s).

How can this be explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual C++, the number of threads executing the loop **does** get reduced with `omp_set_dynamic(1)` in this example, which explains the performance difference.

However, contrary to any good-faith interpretation of the standard (and Visual C++ docs), **`omp_get_num_threads` does not report this reduction**.

The only way to figure out how many threads MSVC *actually* uses for each parallel region is to inspect `omp_get_thread_num` on *every* loop iteration (or parallel task). The following would be one way to do it with little in-loop performance overhead:

```
// std::hardware_destructive_interference_size is not available in gcc or clang, also see comments by Peter Cordes:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680206/understanding-stdhardware-destructive-interference-size-and-stdhardware-cons
struct alignas(2 * std::hardware_destructive_interference_size) NoFalseSharing
{
    int flagValue = 0;
};

void foo()
{
  std::vector<NoFalseSharing> flags(omp_get_max_threads());

#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
  {
    flags[omp_get_thread_num()].flagValue = 1;

    // Your real loop body
  }

  int realOmpNumThreads = 0;
  for (auto flag : flags)
    realOmpNumThreads += flag.flagValue;
}
```

Indeed, you will find `realOmpNumThreads` to yield significantly different values from the `omp_get_num_threads()` inside the parallel region with `omp_set_dynamic(1)` on Visual C++.

---

One could argue that *technically*

- "the number of threads in the **team** executing a parallel region" and
- "the number of threads that are **used** for executing upcoming parallel regions"

are not literally the same.

This is a nonsensical interpretation of the standard in my view, because the intent is very clear and there is no reason for the standard to say "*The number of threads in the team executing a parallel region **stays fixed** for the duration of that parallel region and **is reported** by the `omp_get_num_threads` function*" in this section if this number is unrelated to the functionality of `omp_set_dynamic`.

However, it could be that MSVC decided to keep the number of threads in a **team** unaffected and just **assign no loop iterations for execution** to a subset of them under `omp_set_dynamic(1)` for ease of implementation.

Whatever the case may be: **Do not trust `omp_get_num_threads` in Visual C++.**