# no member named 'hardware_constructive_interference_size' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, c++17

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size), to determine if `std::hardware_constructive_interference_size` is usable it uses the following example:

```
#include <new>

#ifdef __cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size
    using std::hardware_constructive_interference_size;
    using std::hardware_destructive_interference_size;
#else
    // 64 bytes on x86-64 │ L1_CACHE_BYTES │ L1_CACHE_SHIFT │ __cacheline_aligned │ ...
    constexpr std::size_t hardware_constructive_interference_size
        = 2 * sizeof(std::max_align_t);
    constexpr std::size_t hardware_destructive_interference_size
        = 2 * sizeof(std::max_align_t);
#endif
```

However, my system defines `__cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size` but there is no symbol `std::hardware_constructive_interference_size`.

How can I handle this situation?
Is there a way to check if a symbol is defined?

- Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
- macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (MacBook Pro 2019)

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(untitled4)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3")
if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fopenmp")
endif()

add_executable(untitled4 main.cpp)
```

Comment: What value does `__cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size` have if you print it? Is it `>= 201703L`? When reading [an old LLVM mail thread](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2018-May/058073.html) I noticed that they were very reluctant to actually add it to their library and thought about writing a defect report to the standards committee instead.

Comment: It prints `201703`. That's strange... according to the comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39887282/8176989 the author of the proposal works at the Apple Clang team.

Comment: Well, a proposal has to come from _somewhere_ :-) Afaik, gcc has not implemented this either.  I'm surprised that the feature test macro "lies" though. My `clang++-12` (on linux) does not define that macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I handle this situation?

You could detect the broken language implementation using pre-defined macros and make an exception for it.

Detection could be made by trying to compile and run a small program:

```
#include <new>

int main() {
#ifdef __cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size
    // return 0 if the interference_sizes are defined
    return !(std::hardware_constructive_interference_size &&
             std::hardware_destructive_interference_size);
#else
    return 1; // no interference_sizes
#endif
}
```

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -o hwisize hwisize.cpp 2>/dev/null && ./hwisize
has_hw_interference_sizes=$?
```

- If the compilation fails, `has_hw_interference_sizes` will be `1`.
- If the compilation succeeds, but `__cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size` is not defined, `has_hw_interference_sizes` will be `1`.
- If the compilation succeeds, and `__cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size` is defined, `has_hw_interference_sizes` will be `0`.

(The reversed `bool` logic is how common shells define `true` (0) and `false` (not 0))

Just plug that into your build system.

Comment: How can I detect the broken language implementation using pre-defined macros?

Comment: @김선달 I added one way to the answer. Hope eerorika is ok with that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks! It's sad that the language itself cannot handle this.

Comment: @김선달 the feature test macro is supposed to be enough but if there's a flaw in the implementation there's very little one can do but to actually test it.