# TSan race disappears with alignas(32)

Tags: c++, lock-free, thread-sanitizer

I have an implementation of a lockfree queue, which I believe to be correct (or at least data race-free):

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <thread>

struct Job {
  int id;
  int data;
};

class JobQueue {
  using stdmo = std::memory_order;

  struct Node {
    std::atomic<Node *> next = QUEUE_END;
    Job job;
  };

  static inline Node *const QUEUE_END = nullptr;
  static inline Node *const STACK_END = QUEUE_END + 1;

  struct GenNodePtr {
    Node *node;
    std::uintptr_t gen;
  };

  alignas(64) std::atomic<Node *> jobs_back;
  alignas(64) std::atomic<GenNodePtr> jobs_front;
  alignas(64) std::atomic<GenNodePtr> stack_top;

 public:
  JobQueue()
      : jobs_back{new Node{}},
        jobs_front{GenNodePtr{jobs_back.load(stdmo::relaxed), 1}},
        stack_top{GenNodePtr{STACK_END, 1}} {}

  ~JobQueue() {
    Node *cur_queue = jobs_front.load(stdmo::relaxed).node;
    while (cur_queue != QUEUE_END) {
      Node *next = cur_queue->next;
      delete cur_queue;
      cur_queue = next;
    }

    Node *cur_stack = stack_top.load(stdmo::relaxed).node;
    while (cur_stack != STACK_END) {
      Node *next = cur_stack->next;
      delete cur_stack;
      cur_stack = next;
    }
  }

  Node *allocate_node() {
    GenNodePtr cur_stack = stack_top.load(stdmo::acquire);
    while (true) {
      if (cur_stack.node == STACK_END) {
        return new Node{};
      }
      Node *cur_stack_next = cur_stack.node->next.load(stdmo::relaxed);
      GenNodePtr new_stack{cur_stack_next, cur_stack.gen + 1};
      if (stack_top.compare_exchange_weak(cur_stack, new_stack,
                                          stdmo::acq_rel)) {
        return cur_stack.node;
      }
    }
  }

  void deallocate_node(Node *node) {
    GenNodePtr cur_stack = stack_top.load(stdmo::acquire);
    while (true) {
      node->next.store(cur_stack.node, stdmo::relaxed);
      GenNodePtr new_stack{node, cur_stack.gen + 1};
      if (stack_top.compare_exchange_weak(cur_stack, new_stack,
                                          stdmo::acq_rel)) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

 public:
  void enqueue(Job job) {
    Node *new_node = allocate_node();
    new_node->next.store(QUEUE_END, stdmo::relaxed);
    Node *old_dummy = jobs_back.exchange(new_node, stdmo::acq_rel);
    old_dummy->job = job;
    old_dummy->next.store(new_node, stdmo::release);
  }

  std::optional<Job> try_dequeue() {
    GenNodePtr old_front = jobs_front.load(stdmo::relaxed);
    while (true) {
      Node *old_front_next = old_front.node->next.load(stdmo::acquire);
      if (old_front_next == QUEUE_END) {
        return std::nullopt;
      }

      GenNodePtr new_front{old_front_next, old_front.gen + 1};
      if (jobs_front.compare_exchange_weak(old_front, new_front,
                                           stdmo::relaxed)) {
        break;
      }
    }

    Job job = old_front.node->job;
    deallocate_node(old_front.node);

    return job;
  }
};

int main() {
  JobQueue queue;

  std::atomic<int> i = 0;

  std::thread consumer{[&queue, &i]() {
    // producer enqueues 1
    while (i.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != 1) {}
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel);

    std::cout << queue.try_dequeue().value_or(Job{-1, -1}).data
              << std::endl;

    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel);
    i.store(2, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    // producer enqueues 2 and 3
  }};

  std::thread producer{[&queue, &i]() {
    queue.enqueue(Job{1, 1});

    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel);
    i.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    // consumer consumes here

    while (i.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != 2) {}
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel);

    queue.enqueue(Job{2, 2});
    queue.enqueue(Job{3, 3});
  }};

  producer.join();
  consumer.join();

  return 0;
}
```

This queue is implemented as a singly-linked double ended linked list. It uses a dummy node to decouple producers and consumers, and it uses a generation counter and node recycling (using an internal stack) to avoid the ABA problem and a use-after-free in `try_dequeue`.

Running this under TSan compiled with Clang 13.0.1, Linux x64, I get the following race:

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=223081)
  Write of size 8 at 0x7b0400000008 by thread T2:
    #0 JobQueue::enqueue(Job) .../bug4.cpp:85 (bug4.tsan+0xe3e53)
    #1 operator() .../bug4.cpp:142 (bug4.tsan+0xe39ee)
    ...

  Previous read of size 8 at 0x7b0400000008 by thread T1:
    #0 JobQueue::try_dequeue() .../bug4.cpp:104 (bug4.tsan+0xe3c07)
    #1 operator() .../bug4.cpp:121 (bug4.tsan+0xe381c)
    ...
```

[Run on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXABx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEjaSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIGZmpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcQm2mPaOAkIETMQEWT5%2BXAF2mA4ZdQ0ERRHRsfGJCvWNzTlttmN9oQOlQwkAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQmO25MRCx4pjvYJhoAgrv7h5gnZ06jxJisp3ePzwYBy8x1OHiSNWYtD%2B9yeZj2QNe7zcBAQ3yY6BhAMeXy8DiOAClUFETgB2KyPI5HUIEamYnYUh5UmlHdAXJinRkmUkAEU5sNhByYCgUhOJAEUvJgpWTGVSvGkjEdRugWKh3jzlQR0CAQGw1cQAJ4AfRIWGI/OxTK1xDxtPCGDe3LlVK1OpAF1QVxubgdxwAVH8jmFVLTTprxXJsFHjdhwnyGbDXWKSdpiZbrdyE1zKVqLtdqQxaHMjn63v60AxRkdI9HsLH4xrg15aLQIRbE7nRvnkIXi2FS46jhWBNWhAAVB5uADSDc14ZrUZjcfnliOXAzSZtdqOAHFGGXlARiLKt1Sy8OGI6M8mVbqvDT28bacBGDeydmBbmxHhgMwFBAABsAAsSxurqnremCF6BrcRxplECjGlETDIAA1u%2BP5/sKQGgeBHqXNcYL7gwh7HkGCFIVQxCyJhxbYQBIFgXeBFekRZwkWRHbYHm6HPqgSSbpSSReFExbICAW5ElEkrSpgEBLGerogPBxJISh6HOmEADug5YM6WZZqQSnJpRxrUbR5KcY6R4WuSZkaWhAB0tCoBiEAqmqurfAYqiYOgKzroZvLGbmyZUt2fFEIJVkHjZ5HkhOU6ziupBBbyWanhlVpUgAftJslSgpp5hXp5bIOsxoAI5SjKC5mRZgguW56AedqXkgD5TB%2BQFTlXvpnbWlS2kIHQbwQBVxDVbVbxgGAC61su8ZgQZpXnkO/ohmGOyapN01yQAtH8W3vsmWD0AQbx7TVcmna610zU2J2Dcmhk5a6MF7ZFaFNt9/FJM17meag3lVN1/lLH114va6I1jUcE2Vd9RxzQuSUznOK3kiZZWXpgoZNl99ToUdtzPS6Z1VJgl1HETqEYTDyZ0%2BhT34wQd1vZm2VPLmMFiK5oiXca/XyVjFN7nFWC2bTSPEz9C5/dFgOtcDEHIDVeDfIpjNHHD9AI8eUpizjeBUAjzPOSLGpo5OGMrsba2ut8BDrAwwaYLpZYGRlOtUpz4W4xWsv08LbOE8H6FQ1gpPYFtyttaqIOdWDPXa%2BLVLWVLx7u9pxrfc6Fuh6GaUW05r5u9Y6Wfo7psI4rAlOWgLBJA0mDGvjyAIIYr7GtpPxoYjU3fWlOl53LoVDQHU/TzPM%2Bqx66vGj5SwO5PybO67MtD3LUeYHdfvc69h8fl%2B1oAG6oHg6Csj8raoILbcixAMEi6vyaZyo2cW79cv/fH8%2BoQ1lrO6etxqG0wG/cKIsY5x1GCQeSpcRZpXnl1VO%2B8JakXiieUe%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%2BfJ3pUkMfkhciLzl/AQndLAViH7Czsby1%2BQlJ6/LdgKmGKiKGnxZCwJgoRiqrWtAVR6QzJURXaaxKCHxBBBjwE2DQOr8KonRNfSsCgfCxAMgAVisGYQCQy0rmEAngEwDqeRquxqVAA9AGo4SQaKhM2CePRM1RQblKusiAeB/56v1CQE0ZpYhpPBgFFG813lcGNqy/CkFrjPjRD8fZjBNgJ11Cmo0ppiDmmNGI5e5rdXujQF4babgwRHCGU5fpITMBDIUk5M%2BYgpT1ogL08kB0uBpVnVmSGbJ6g42nmCHtLFXDQkGkpFixbkClqteZSt8kWK1rTQ2jNzaJF3UTW4%2BSiR8LnvrY2vxAVW1HCDSGsNeJYi6IYEM0UZgjiGGvjsLcwVq482tCxS15bv0YF/XZKwTqPVutIZ671vqGV9qjXJKd6ZyRzqrhkjlRbCIHrgxiY9QJT3JswAaC9jbr3pNvZU%2BBEBiNnoY6ml9Ga32keg8mL9Nq7UnlE2wUUCBYh7zI/GxNVzq16h43W9NU0BM5oXGYAt7LJ57oo4e8tNGq3ccY3xqaLHBNKVwwBmaBGojOkfWYRdd0bPDunRYHYaVwO8kE2ywyO7cyhsQxGpyaZVV%2BdpqOMTYXL4MHsYF600qjhmp3dzDgKxaCcAdbwPwHAtCkBBhwbtlhK4KDWBsJ08IeCkAIJoDLKw0IgAdVwJyGgHWki4KSECgEdiSB2KSAAnN1/QnBgK8BYP4DQbWNCzbm/N2bc68sFaK7wBQIAAh1fyxl0gcBYBIHxp0TtJByCUAaMABQyhDBVCEAgVA2k8s1foXQfMAgrthFoLd%2B7y3eDPfoHEIURguA7A0HOv7sQADynavsPfq4EPyyAHjEAu5wXgh3kB1HwHl3g/BBAiDEOwLgwEZCCEUCodQ23SC6DnQYIwKBrDWH0HgRC8AVidIyOtjgB0VThlMKVywZgNBHAOhDnYwuqAKEMOkAAXnvHaVHr4HQMBRtbFXNh6BVKEd7N27uw%2B4LwY8mAtg1e0sQJgSROA8Ey9l3LcOivYAR8dk8qhJCAQOiBWmtPgDrh2G1pyXAEYledTYI4uBCAkFITsfNBv6sr1IE14CkgnKDeAmYSQ8IHU7EAlwQCguvNZY4ON0gP3Cuo9sBt2rsfrccDMLbynq3K/bbj2fWIaRnDASAA%3D%3D%3D) (note, because of how Godbolt runs the program, TSan doesn't show line number information)

This race is between this previous read in `try_dequeue` called from the `consumer` thread:

```cpp
    Job job = old_front.node->job;
```

and this later write in `enqueue`, which is the third call to `enqueue` by the `producer` thread:

```cpp
    old_dummy->job = job;
```

I believe this race to be impossible, because the `producer` thread should synchronise with the `consumer` thread via the acquire-release compare-exchange to `stack_top` in `allocate_node` and `deallocate_node`.

Now, the weird thing is that making `GenNodePointer` `alignas(32)` removes the race.

[Run on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXABx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM2akrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxP6BAA6oCoRODB7evgmkyamOAqHhUSyx8QG2mPYFDEIETMQEmT5%2BFXaYDul1DQRFkTFxOQr1jc3ZbSO9Yf2lgwEAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMxhyN5YANQmm25MRCx4ppvYJhoAgls7e5iHx07DxJisR9d3Dwy7XgORw8iRqYm%2BN3uZm2/yeLzcBAQHyY6Ahvzu7y8Dn2AClUNFDgB2Kx3fb7MIEcmozYk25kin7dCnJhHWkmQkAEVZkMhuyYCgUuPxAEUvJgxUTaWSvKkjPthugWKgXhz5QR0CAQGwlcQAJ4AfRIWGI3PRdLVxCxlIiGGe7KlZLVGpAp1Q50ubhtBwAVN99uFVJSjqrhXJsGH9dgIlyaZDHUKCdp8abzeyY2zSWrThdyQxaNN9l7nt60AxhvtQ%2BHsJHoyr/V5aLRQSbY5nhtnkLn8%2BFC7b9iWBOWhAAVW5uADSNdVwYrYYjUenln2XBTcYtVv2YjwwGYCggmzM832AHFGEXlARiJK12Si/2GLaU/GFZqvBTm/rKcBGE%2BiemeZmW47vyEAAGwACxHi%2BLpnBcwJ3r6Vz7Em0QKPq0RMMgADWv5AbuYGQU6mquu6wKngw56Xn6KFoVQxCyLh%2BbAXuEFQeqxGwR65GUS22BZthn6oIkq6kokXjRPmyAgGueLRKK4qYBA8w3o6IDIfiaEYdh9rhAA7r2WD2mmaakCp8Y0fqdEMcS3G2heJrEhZWlYQAdLQqAohACpKpqHwGKomDoIsy7GZypmZvGZLtgJRDCTZZ52VRxIjmOk4LqQIWcmm15ZWaZIAH6yfJYpKdeEUGcWyArPqACOYoSjOFlWYIbkeegXnqj5IB%2BUwAVBS5D6Ga25pkrpCB0M8EBVcQtX1c8YBgDOlbztGR5GeVt59t6AZBpsqrTbNCkALTfDtv7xlg9AEM8B11Qp52Ordc11mdw3xsZeWOghB3RVhda/YJiStZ53moL5VS9YF8wDY%2Bb2OmNE37FN1W/fsC0zilE5TmtxJmRV96YIGdY/fU2EnVcr0OhdVSYNd%2Bwk5hOFw/GDPYS9hMEA9H2prl9yZghYjuaI136oNik41TJ4JVg9n0yjpN/TOAOxcD7Wg8RyB1XgHzKcz%2BwI/QSOXmKEt43gVBI6zrliyqGOjljC6mxtjofAQKwMP6mD6UWRlZXrZLc5F%2BMlvLjOixzxOh9hMNYOT2A7arHWKmD3UQ31uuS2Stky5enu6fqv32lb4eBhlVsud%2BHvWJl/7O%2BbSPK0JLloCwiQNJg%2BqE8gCCGN%2B%2Bq6Z8WHIzNv0ZXpBcK%2BFI1BzPs9z3P6supr%2Bp%2BfMTvT/Grvu3LI8KzHmAPQHvPvcff4AeaABuqB4OgjKfI2qDCx3YsQAhYvr/G2cqLnVv/QrgOJ0XphLWOsHoG0msbTAH9IpizjgnYYJBFLlzFhlRePV06HylhRRKV5x6F2JCgneE9GYV0YIcJcK4/aZ3JBbDqYcVYtzbh8Tuqhu69w7gPJgQ8rZjy9sQ7CU955COEQvTqKdgEryqGvMqG9HTRGREzahgdHTKO5nGMSEkLjSUzFfG%2B%2BxGB3RKrJdS0RoGbR9OPG2M5BaP1OM/W0SkHqWNtHAjmLkEEfAgMtas6UnRdXQVDB6CFPDoH1OgHwLBdR1iciQruPcjCKWcVgVBYiNY1UkbQDOKkQlhIibqOOKFonJj1jk8JLBImuMDO4ognikmYBScncG9B%2BRQN/Gots7EQBCTBLQYEsk/SXgNFgQx4sZGf2lt/K8OTmq7VVE1eiLV3Ig1SanfygS9bgKNpaKBYzIrBNoKEmZJdZn7GmQsgg%2B9KkXKWWrFZwC3ygP9jQpGZzZDHNtntWcVZsa7KDlvYgHtoIMAbO5UEmD2myK/rLceMz7SvMEMcjK8KLmV3IRYGumD64QHmbIZubomEdziew/ug8IDIt4fnGZgiRE0tpWgtOUMzGRXkYPcFp8j5ck%2BmSYxhSZzIsud8FCD0sA2KfqLBx/L34iWnv8j2Qq4ZqKoefBkLAmBhFKutc0RVnojOlVFTpJE4KvEEH6PAdYNB6qIiAREyJb6lgUD4OIRkACsVgzCgRGRlcwoE8AmGdRyDVuNyoAHpg37ESPRcJawrwGLmoKFc5VNkQDwIAzp2oSAGiNHEDJkMgpo0Wp8rgpt2VWsNcgT8SJPiHMYGsJOmp016kNMQY0%2BoJGr0tfq50aAvC7TcMCfYIyXKDLCZgEZSkXIXzEGKJtEB%2BnEiOlwDKC60zQyZPUPGs9gT9ugq4Xpw0VLQTLRW21lka2KWgg2zNzbs1tqkQ9FNHjFKBCtZeptLaAlBQ7fsUN4bI1YjiPohgIzBRmE3AwW%2Bmw1yhVrnzc00EbVVt/Rgf9DkrCuu9Z68hPq/UBqZYO2NClZ3JmJIumuWSuWls4seqtp7/jnrTZgHUV6W23syfe6piCICkYvYxjNb7s0fvI7B%2BMP77WOqvGJtggoEBxAPhRpNKabl1q1LxxtWaZqCfzTOQ8OVOXT0PVRhDKJaO1p40x/jM1WNCZUvhoDc0iPRHtM%2BswK6Hq2bHXOiwmwMqQc5EJjlxl92Zgjch6NLkkzqv8/TQc4nwvXwYI4oL5pZX7Atfu3mHBFi0E4M63gfgOBaFIGDDgfbLDVwUMsVYdpoQ8FIAQTQmXFhYRAM6rgLkNDOsJFwQkEFQKbEkJsQkABOHr%2BhODgV4CwCQGgNDtZm/Nhb83F35cK8V3gCgQAaDqw1xYcBYBIEJh0HtJByCUAaMABQyhDBVCEAgVAul8u1cYXQbMAgrvhFoLd%2B7K3eDPfoPEPkRguCbA0Iuv7cQADyPavsPYa0EAKyBbjEAu5wXgh3kB1HwPl3g/BBAiDEOwLg4EZCCEUCodQBWdB6AMEYFA1hrD6DwKheAixunpA2xwI6CpgymDK5YMwGh9hHQh5sIXVAFCGDSAALwPntIzt8joGE4utyraw9AKjCO9m7d3YfcF4JeTA6xau6WIEwRInAeBZZy3luHxXsAI%2BO1eVQkhQJHQgvTGnwBlybHay5LgSNStupsPsXAhASDkM2EW/XO2msgHApIFyQ3wJmEkNCZ1mxQJcFAgL7z2WOATdID9orqPbCbe25TteY2OBmBt5T4vHBo8V8WBfOIqRnDgSAA%3D%3D%3D)

Questions:

1. Is this race actually possible?
2. Why does increasing the alignment of GenNodePointer make TSan no longer register a race?

Comment: OT: Those `alignas(64)` are there to avoid false sharing? If so, you might want to look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199779/false-sharing-and-128-byte-alignment-padding

Comment: @DanielLangr: Yeah, they are. That's cool, thanks for that!